# Installation gmp library for C language. Installation libtool failure

Tags: c, gmp, libtool

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7txRF.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtHrk.png)I need a help with following. I did try install C gmp library with Cygwin. At final of executing `make install` appears a menssage:
`warning: remember to run 'libtool --finish /c:/c++/GMP/libraries/lib'`
Though, at to run `libtool --finish...` it appears a menssage `libtool command not found`.
In fact, running `make check` it becomes `libtool not installed`.
Further that, the directory above does not exist. Instead, it was created with the installation one `C:/cygwin64/libraries/lib`. But with this directory it appears the same menssage `libtool command not found`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is `libtool` there after you run `./configure`?

Comment: It seems libtool was installed, but not entirely. At final running make install, some itens libtool were said installed, but no all.

Comment: Maybe you need to run autoreconf? For example like this: `mkdir -p m4 && autoreconf -f -i -I m4 ` and then run `./configure` again.

Comment: Using `mkdir -p m4 && autoreconf -f -i -I m4` in the terminal the response is `command not found` again. I add one print of console window at to run `make install`, related libtool. The link for image is above.

Comment: Other image was appended, related with the compilation. I tried to creat enviroment variables for console to find the `gmp.h` file, as well libgmp file and other files, but this was not successful... I find that is because the libtool installation has a some problem.

Comment: Pake sure you have `pkg-config` installed and that the location of `gmp.pc` is in the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable. That should help `./configure` find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done! I read somewhere that Cygwin or MinGW does not have one option `./configure` for free GMP library. Instead use the package manager. However, the package manager version is older. If you want to have the current version, you will need a GNU/Linux distro.

Comment: *"the package manager"* Which one? In my MSYS2 there's GMP 6.2.1, which seems to be the latest version.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Now that I couldn't tell you.  I just edited the answer to make it easier to read.